# How to attach extra data on eagerloaded relationship Laravel

Tags: laravel, eager-loading

I have this function that eagerloads the posts,

```
public function getUserPosts()
{
    return User::with('posts')->where("organization_id", $this->getOrganization()->id)->get()->toArray();
}
```

This returns fine the user with posts, my question is can I add some extra data on eagerload something like

```
    public function getUserPosts()
    {
        return User::with('posts', function(){

         //say I fetch an array of posts here, 
        // I want to attach this array of posts with the eagerloaded posts 

        })->where("organization_id", $this->getOrganization()->id)->get()->toArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```php
return User::with(['posts', function($query){
          //here you have the query to the relationship, and can do normal query stuff with it
          //like this:
          $query->with('comments')->select('id', 'title')->where('created_at','>',Carbon::now());

        }])->where("organization_id", $this->getOrganization()->id)->get()->toArray();
```